# How do I add an XML Doc Comment to a ClassDeclarationSyntax in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I have some code that builds a class:

```
return SyntaxFactory
    .ClassDeclaration(name)
    .AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))
    .WithMembers(GetProperties());
```

This all works, and outputs the class that I expect. I'd like to add an XML doc to this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Some plain text here.
/// </summary>
```

I don't need anything fancy, just plain text. I'm struggling to find any examples of this, and have been through various overloads of `Annotations`, `Trivia`, and loads of methods hanging off `SyntaxFactory` (`XmlComment`, `XmlElementStartTag`, `DocumentationCommentExterior`, `DocumentationCommentTrivia`) with no joy (ironically, none of these have XML Comments!). The closest I got was something that compiled, but crashed at runtime with `Unexpected false`!

I'm targetting .NET 4.5, using VS 2015 RC and 1.0.0-rc2 of Roslyn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [RoslynQuoter](http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/) to see how to do this:

```
        SyntaxFactory.ClassDeclaration(
            @"C")
        .WithKeyword(
            SyntaxFactory.Token(
                SyntaxFactory.TriviaList(
                    SyntaxFactory.Trivia(
                        SyntaxFactory.DocumentationCommentTrivia(
                            SyntaxKind.SingleLineDocumentationCommentTrivia,
                            SyntaxFactory.List<XmlNodeSyntax>(
                                new XmlNodeSyntax[]{
                                    SyntaxFactory.XmlText()
                                    .WithTextTokens(
                                        SyntaxFactory.TokenList(
                                            SyntaxFactory.XmlTextLiteral(
                                                SyntaxFactory.TriviaList(
                                                    SyntaxFactory.DocumentationCommentExterior(
                                                        @"///")),
                                                @" ",
                                                @" ",
                                                SyntaxFactory.TriviaList()))),
                                    SyntaxFactory.XmlElement(
                                        SyntaxFactory.XmlElementStartTag(
                                            SyntaxFactory.XmlName(
                                                SyntaxFactory.Identifier(
                                                    @"summary"))),
                                        SyntaxFactory.XmlElementEndTag(
                                            SyntaxFactory.XmlName(
                                                SyntaxFactory.Identifier(
                                                    @"summary"))))
                                    .WithContent(
                                        SyntaxFactory.SingletonList<XmlNodeSyntax>(
                                            SyntaxFactory.XmlText()
                                            .WithTextTokens(
                                                SyntaxFactory.TokenList(
                                                    new []{
                                                        SyntaxFactory.XmlTextNewLine(
                                                            SyntaxFactory.TriviaList(),
                                                            @"
",
                                                            @"
",
                                                            SyntaxFactory.TriviaList()),
                                                        SyntaxFactory.XmlTextLiteral(
                                                            SyntaxFactory.TriviaList(
                                                                SyntaxFactory.DocumentationCommentExterior(
                                                                    @"///")),
                                                            @" Some plain text here.",
                                                            @" Some plain text here.",
                                                            SyntaxFactory.TriviaList()),
                                                        SyntaxFactory.XmlTextNewLine(
                                                            SyntaxFactory.TriviaList(),
                                                            @"
",
                                                            @"
",
                                                            SyntaxFactory.TriviaList()),
                                                        SyntaxFactory.XmlTextLiteral(
                                                            SyntaxFactory.TriviaList(
                                                                SyntaxFactory.DocumentationCommentExterior(
                                                                    @"///")),
                                                            @" ",
                                                            @" ",
                                                            SyntaxFactory.TriviaList())})))),
                                    SyntaxFactory.XmlText()
                                    .WithTextTokens(
                                        SyntaxFactory.TokenList(
                                            SyntaxFactory.XmlTextNewLine(
                                                SyntaxFactory.TriviaList(),
                                                @"
",
                                                @"
",
                                                SyntaxFactory.TriviaList())))})))),
                SyntaxKind.ClassKeyword,
                SyntaxFactory.TriviaList()))))
```

Comment: Awesome; thanks! (slightly more verbose than I hoped!)

Comment: @DannyTuppeny: You can probably omit a lot of that.

Comment: Yep, I can see a lot of cruft (like newlines) I probably don't need (I'm running through the Formatter before spitting to disk), but it's a great starting point (and this tool will save lots of similar questions!)

Comment: @DannyTuppeny did you find a shorter way to do this?

Comment: @LOST I think I ended up switching to just building my code via strings. The APIs felt like more work than they were worth :(

Answer (score 8):

try this one:

```
var doc = @"
/// <summary>
/// Some plain text here.
/// </summary>
";
return SyntaxFactory.Comment(doc);
```

Comment: It would be better to use `SyntaxFactory.ParseLeadingTrivia(doc)`

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
var tokens = docText.Split('\n')
    .Select(line => XmlTextLiteral(line))
    .ToList();
for(int i = 1; i < tokens.Count; i += 2)
    tokens.Insert(i, XmlTextNewLine("\n"));

var summary = XmlElement("summary",
    SingletonList<XmlNodeSyntax>(XmlText(TokenList(tokens))));
SyntaxTriviaList doc = TriviaList(
    Trivia(DocumentationComment(summary, XmlText("\n"))));
return member.WithLeadingTrivia(doc);
```

As you noticed, one needs to manually insert XmlTextNewLine for every line separator in summary.
The final `XmlText("\n")` is there to ensure member definition actually starts on a new line after `/// </summary>`

I have not actually tested that in Visual Studio (e.g. haven't checked tooltips out). You might need to generate `<p>`, `<para>`, `<br/>`, or something like that around every newline

Answer (score 0):

As already noted parsing works and you can build yourself with the necessary XmlText newline.

Here is an extension method class that you can base on.  Note that there are classes for the different documentation xml elements.  For instance XmlValueElement and XmlSummaryElement below.

```
public static class XmlComments
{
    private static TMember AddSimple<TMember>(this TMember member,XmlElementSyntax xmlElement) where TMember:MemberDeclarationSyntax
    {
        return member.WithLeadingTrivia(
                TriviaList(
                    Trivia(
                        DocumentationComment(
                            xmlElement,
                            XmlText().WithTextTokens(
                                TokenList(
                                    Token(
                                        TriviaList(),
                                        SyntaxKind.XmlTextLiteralNewLineToken,
                                        Environment.NewLine,
                                        Environment.NewLine,
                                        TriviaList()
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
    }
    public static PropertyDeclarationSyntax AddValue(this PropertyDeclarationSyntax property,string value)
    {
        return property.AddSimple(
            XmlValueElement(
                XmlText(value)
            ));
    }
    public static TMember AddSummary<TMember>(this TMember member, string value) where TMember: MemberDeclarationSyntax
    {
        return member.AddSimple(
            XmlSummaryElement(
                XmlText(value)
            ));
    }
}
```